# What is heap write traffic and why it is required in ArrayList?

Tags: java

I was just curious to know what does [heap write traffic](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l878) means and why it was required in ArrayList implementation?

Snippet of `ArrayList` implementation, see the line with the comment

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> consumer) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(consumer);
    final int size = ArrayList.this.size;
    int i = cursor;
    if (i >= size) {
        return;
    }
    final Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
    if (i >= elementData.length) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
    while (i != size && modCount == expectedModCount) {
        consumer.accept((E) elementData[i++]);
    }
    // update once at end of iteration to reduce heap write traffic
    cursor = i;
    lastRet = i - 1;
    checkForComodification();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that author wanted to use local variable `i` due to possibility of it being stack allocated when [escape analysis and stack allocation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html) kicks in. Unlike `cursor` the `i` variable is changed multiple times due to `i++` statement inside the `while` loop. It should be cheaper to increment it on the stack and skip all Java Memory Model implications. `Iterator.cursor` is a member field and it's probably always on the heap especially that `Iterator` objects are passed around in the user code.

Answer (score 3):

Usually the `cursor` variable points to the next element to be returned by an `Iterator`. So when iterating you would need to update the `cursor` variable each time such that it keeps pointing to the correct element.

However, the `forEachRemaining` method completes the iteration on its own. It's not meant to be paused. As such, you can ignore to update the cursor variable until the method has finished. While the method iterates the `cursor` will then point to a wrong element. But as you can't pause the method it does not make any difference.

By that you reduce the amount of allocations to `cursor` and by that the *heap traffic*. So they refer to a *more correct* implementation like

```
while (i != size && modCount == expectedModCount) {
    consumer.accept((E) elementData[i++]);
    // Update cursor while iterating
    cursor = i;
}
```

Or using the cursor directly instead of an additional `i`

```
while (cursor != size && modCount == expectedModCount) {
    consumer.accept((E) elementData[cursor++]);
}
```

But then you work on a member variable instead of a local variable `i`. It's cheaper to work with `i`, for details see the answer of @kdowbecki.

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore all the guard-conditions, `next()` does the following:

```
public E next() {
    Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;

    int i = cursor;
    cursor = i + 1;
    lastRet = i;
    return (E) elementData[i];
}
```

`forEachRemaining()` will essentially keep calling `next()` and invoke the consumer on each element, so if we did that, inlining the `next()` logic, we get:

```
public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> consumer) {
    final int size = ArrayList.this.size;
    final Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;

    int i = cursor;
    while (i != size) { // same as hasNext()
        // begin: consumer.accept(next())
        cursor = i + 1;
        lastRet = i;
        consumer.accept((E) elementData[i]);
        // end: consumer.accept(next())
        i++;
    }
}
```

Since both `cursor` and `lastRet` are fields, they exist on the heap, while `i` exist on the stack.

To reduce the number of memory writes, the update of `cursor` and `lastRet` can be moved outside the loop, since they are not actually used inside the loop.

Of course, you're now doing that after one extra `i++`, so you need to subtract `1` from `i`.

```
public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> consumer) {
    final int size = ArrayList.this.size;
    final Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;

    int i = cursor;
    while (i != size) {
        consumer.accept((E) elementData[i++]);
    }
    cursor = i;
    lastRet = i - 1;
}
```

The effect is that only the stack variable `i` is updated, and the two heap values are left alone, during the iteration.

Once JIT kicks in, if the `accept()` call is inlined, the stack variable `i` might even be eliminated and become just a register value, greatly reducing the number of updates to "slow" memory.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for providing the answers. To explain better I am adding how internal Java memory model looks like as in the figure below. As pointed out by @kdowbecki, @Zabuza and @Andreas, it is efficient to use `Thread Stack` memory for local execution then to use `Heap` memory for every iteration. It might fall under the category of [amortized analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis).

[image: Figure 1]

It is also interesting to check [memory model of a process](http://operatingsystempoly.blogspot.in/p/process-concept.html) (JVM being a process) in operating systems.

[image: Process memory]